# What nice map can allow streets on top of polygons

Tags: mapping, gis, geocoding

I would like to use something like google, mapquest, bing, or openlayers to try and get something that looks like

http://screencast.com/t/qZejYb0L3Er

where the major streets are unaffected by the polygon overlay.

Can someone point me in the right direction. From the google api documentation it would appear i cant get under the roads so... looking for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using http://www.mapdotnet.com/ with background from open maps. Custom middle cache tiles from shape files stored in SQL, on top we have open street layer (or can use bing)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Google Maps by changing the order of the layers.
[**This is an API V2 example**](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_main.html?lat=40.446947&lon=-90.834961&z=5&mType=19), but you can achieve the same result with the current version, which is V3.